# time complexity is order of n or square of n if i use same variables for nested loops

Tags: c, loops, time, nested, complexity-theory

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   for(;arr[i]!=' ';i++)
       {
       //required code
       }
//required code
}
```

Suppose I want to do some operation like 'reversing each and every word of a sentence (but not sentence as a whole. Example: 
Input: "This is a ball"
Output: "sihT si a llab"
'. 
Then definitely inside the loop, I will look for a 'Space' character. I want to ask following things:
(1) The way, I have used two loops, why do people say that I am unnecessarily making the program more complex by making it O(n^2).
I know I could use 'if' inside the outer 'for' loop in place of inner 'for'. But, if I choose this way, how could this be O(n^2), as I think I am increasing the loops over same variable 'i', I think it is O(n).
(2)Why "what I have written" (inner for loop in place of 'if') is not considered a good practice? Does it have to do a lot with cache issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your double loop has a time complexity of `O(n)`, since the total number of iterations is `n`.

Modifing the loop variable of a `for` loop is considered bad practice. I would use `while` loops instead.

Note that the inner loop has a bug - it needs to check that it doesn't continue past the end of the buffer.

Comment: I got your point. If there is no space in the sentence it inner loop will go beyond null. But what about using while. How would you use while?
while(arr[i]!=' ')
{
i++;
}
Won't there be the same problem again?

Comment: The bug is a separate issue and has to be handled regardless. For example: `while(i<n && arr[i]!=' '){ i++; }`

Comment: while(i<n && arr[i]!=' '){ i++; } ---    v/s ---   if(arr[i]==' ') {//code}
Is using if better or both are same? (if we keep in mind all the issues eg cache locality)

Comment: `if` is probably easier to understand in this case since then you only have one loop. Performance should be similar. If it really matters you would have to compare the generated assembly code.